# Alternatives to "break a butterfly on a wheel"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, idiom-requests

The phrase "to break a butterfly on a wheel" is very evocative, but I can't bring myself to use it: I find the "wheel" too disturbing.

So: what are some good alternatives?

(For those who are unfamiliar with this expression, Brewer's *Dictionary of Phrase and Fable* defines it as "to employ superabundant effort in the accomplishment of a small matter". [[link](https://books.google.com/books?id=pgoPAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA173&dq=to-break-a-butterfly-on-a-wheel)])

Comment: I don't blame you: I find disturbing the very idea of harming a fellow creature, one of such delicate grace and sublime beauty. That the wheel was used as a medieval torture device adds sadistic insult to gratuitous injury.

Comment: "to break a butterfly on a wheel" was used by Alexander Pope  (around 1730) and it may be a bit dated today.

Comment: @rogermue: Well, Pope also gave us "faint praise", and probably lots of other expressions that we wouldn't bat an eye at. (And, I mean, he also used plenty of normal words like *the* and *of* and *lock*.) But you're right -- I ended my question with an explanation of what the phrase *meant*, which I wouldn't have bothered to do if I had felt that this were an everyday expression that everyone understood today.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[*Use a sledgehammer to crack a nut.*](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/use+a+sledgehammer+to+crack+a+nut)

> to do something with more force than is necessary to achieve the
>   result you want
>
> When he sent ten men to arrest one small boy, he clearly used a
>   sledgehammer to crack a nut.

Better yet: [*Use a sledgehammer to swat a fly!*](http://www.rediff.com/news/1999/jun/15ashok.htm)

idioms.thefreedictionary.com

Answer (score 9):

Heavy-handed?

> http://www.usingenglish.com/reference/idioms/heavy-handed.html
>
> If someone is heavy-handed, they are insensitive and use excessive force or authority when dealing with a problem.

In other words, I love the Chinese idiom with a similar meaning:

用高射炮打蚊子(literally: to shoot a mosquito with an anti-aircraft gun)

Comment: +1 for Shoot a mosquito with an anti-aircraft gun! Put that one at the top of your answer.

Comment: There's also *nuking the mosquito*.

Answer (score 6):

Overkill is the phrase that comes to mind here. But if you're looking for a colorful animal metaphor, maybe "beat a dead mouse"?

Comment: Thanks! Although "overkill" does seem to be attested as a verb, that use sounds very odd to me. In my own experience it is invariably a mass noun. (And I'm not specifically looking for an animal metaphor, no, though I'm not opposed to one!)

Comment: @ruakh You didn't ask for a verb, but you can have one: "to be overkill" would be a direct substitute for your phrase.

Comment: Possibly you mean the common idiom to "flog a dead horse", which has a slightly different meaning: to continue an action after that action ceases to be useful.

Comment: @Qsigma: Eh? "To be overkill" certainly is *not* a direct substitute. It has the right part of speech, but it takes the wrong subject.

Comment: @ruakh That depends on the sentence you want to write, which you didn't tell us yet. For example, "He hung the cabinet with a hundred nails, which was breaking a butterfly on a wheel" becomes "He hung the cabinet with a hundred nails, which was overkill."

Comment: @Qsigma: There's no specific "the sentence [I] want to write" at the moment. I posted this question shortly after an instance where I wanted to use "break a butterfly on a wheel", but couldn't bring myself to do so; but I'm looking for alternatives in general, for the next time I need to write such a sentence. (And coincidentally, in the instance that led to this question, I *did* end up reworking it a bit and using the word "overkill". So I'm certainly not saying that the suggestion is garbage. But it's not perfect, either, and it's certainly not "a direct substitute".)

Comment: @blmoore - I meant beat a dead mouse as a counterpoint to flog a dead horse. The former indicates action that is no longer -necessary-, while the latter indicates action that is no longer -useful-. Seems different enough to me to justify a different phrase.

Answer (score 6):

There's a whole range of answers concocted in a veritable arms race:

> [That's like using a hammer to kill a ladybug](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/980752)
>   [That's like using a sledgehammer to kill a fly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19983511/2938711)
>   [That's like using a pistol to kill a cockroach](http://cowboyszone.com/threads/hurd-out-with-ankle-injury.125749/)
>   [That's like using a shotgun to kill a mosquito!](http://forum.thefreedictionary.com/postst63383_He-burned-it-.aspx) 
>   [That's like using a bazooka to kill a flea.](http://windowssecrets.com/forums/showthread.php/143269-How-to-export-Facebook-Friend-list)
>   [That's like using a cannon to kill a mosquito](http://forums.gardenweb.com/forums/load/bamboo/msg0507452714343.html?27)
>   [That's like using a nuclear bomb to kill a mosquito](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/minecraft-discussion/survival-mode/2132889-frantic-villagers-what-is-going-on)

Where the butterfly on the wheel goes in that list is unclear-  maybe between the sledgehammer and the pistol.

Answer (score 3):

The figurative language surrounding this concept is generally pretty disturbing: to beat a dead horse, for example. The verb 'belabor' is nice, boring, alternative -- there is the expression 'to belabor the point.'

Answer (score 2):

In German it is common to say

"to shoot with cannons on sparrows" (germ.: "Mit Kanonen auf Spatzen schießen")